# DisplayFor method requires at least 2 parameters as per MSDN, but it seems to work with 1 parameter only

Tags: asp.net, lambda

While learning ASP.Net MVC from tutorial on MSDN, I see DisplayFor method being used as: `@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.SomeProperty)`

or as: `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Releasedate)`

But documentation seems to specify at least 2 parameters ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.displayextensions.displayfor(v=vs.118).aspx)).

One more issue: since `modelItem` parameter is never used on right-side of `=>`, I tried replacing `modelItem` with `()` but get red squiggly line that says `"Type args for method cannot be inferred from usage..."`:

`@Html.DisplayFor(()=> item.Releasedate)`

My main concern is that documentation shows DisplayFor method needs at least 2 parameters, but wherever I saw it in tutorials they only had 1 parameter and that was a lambda expression!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DisplayFor` is an [`extension method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx) of the `HtmlHelper` class. This means that the first argument that you see in MSDN documentation is the HtmlHelper class and there are two ways to call this extension method.

Either on an instance of the `HtmlHelper` class in which case you can omit the first argument (preferred approach):

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.SomeProperty)
```

Or as a plain static method:

```
 @DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor(Html, x => x.SomeProperty)
```

Basically extension methods allow you to *add* methods on existing classes without the need to modify the code of those classes and then use those new methods as if they were first class citizens.

Comment: Oh that was helpful. I couldn't vote your reply because don't have enough privileges :-) But it said by vote was "recorded"! Could you also please guide me how could I have understood these 2 ways of invoking from documentation? I have been reading on this topic for last 6 hrs but couldn't find such info!

Comment: Using the documentation you couldn't have understood this. Extension methods are a basic feature of .NET and are not ASP.NET MVC specific. That's the reason why it is recommended to first learn .NET and then get into ASP.NET MVC  as it uses lots of basic features of the platform.

Comment: Thanks Darin. Could you shed light on why `()` cannot be use `()=>item.Property` ... instead of `modelItem=>item.Property` ... even though modelItem is not used?

Comment: Because this is invalid. The second parameter of the `DisplayFor` extension method is an `Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>`, so it takes one parameter. When you write `() => item.Property`, this is an `Expression<Func<TProperty>>` which is invalid according to the definition of the extension method.

Comment: Great! I guess I should spend more time learning C# before barging on ASP.Net like you said.